# React To PushNotification Received even if the App is Closed

Tags: swift2

I know there are a lot of questions related to this subject, but after searching I found out that they all say that if the app is closed then the only way is to fetch the notification again from the server once the app is opened or if the app is opened from the notification then you can handle it in `didFinishWithLaunch` but using WhatsApp, this is not the case...

I tried sending a message to phone B (which had whatsapp closed), Phone B received the notification. Then I turned off the internet on Phone B and opened the app and still received the chat message.

Can anyone guide me on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use one of [background modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23) - "remote-notification".
After enabling it, you can send push with payload like

`{ 
  "alert": "", 
  "badge": "0", 
  "content-available": 1, 
  "sound": "" 
}`

if you specify **content-available** key equal 1, iOS will wake your app and call `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` in app delegate and you have some time to proceed push and prepare app (like download this new message to device). Here is [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) link with info about push payloads.

However please be aware that this push delivering is not guaranteed. Apple tells

> (Newsstand apps are guaranteed to be able to receive at least one push with this key per 24-hour window.)

In our experience you likely receive it most of the time, but not always. For example app delegate callback will **not** be called if user swiped to close your app.

Also you need to finish execution in 30 seconds or less and call the block in handler parameter (you can check discussion section of method [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) for more details)